# How Can I Use Different Programing Languages in a Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

i saw a BAT file there have different programing language used in there

it is (Java Script)

```
@if (true == false) @end /*
@echo off
bg font 6 & cls
cmdwiz showcursor 0

if defined __ goto :START
set __=.
cmdgfx_input.exe m0unW14x | call %0 %* | cmdgfx_gdi "" Sf0:0,0,180,110W0
set __=
goto :eof

:START
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a F6W=180/2, F6H=110/2
mode %F6W%,%F6H%

cmdwiz getdisplaydim w & set SW=!errorlevel!
cmdwiz getdisplaydim h & set SH=!errorlevel!
cmdwiz getwindowbounds w & set WINW=!errorlevel!
cmdwiz getwindowbounds h & set WINH=!errorlevel!
set /a WPX=%SW%/2-%WINW%/2, WPY=%SH%/2-%WINH%/2-20
cmdwiz setwindowpos %WPX% %WPY%

cscript //nologo //e:javascript "%~dpnx0" %*
::cmdwiz getch & rem Enable this line to see jscript parse errors

mode 80,50
echo "cmdgfx: quit"
title input:Q
endlocal
exit /b 0 */


var W=180, H=110, RY=0
var XMID=W/2, YMID=H/2-53
var DIST=2500, ASPECT=0.6925
var DRAWMODE=0, GROUNDCOL=3, PLYCHAR="db"

var ACCSPEED=270
var MAXCUBES=30

var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")

var HISCORE=0
var inputfile = "hiscore.dat";
if (fs.FileExists(inputfile))
{
    var f1 = fs.OpenTextFile(inputfile, 1)  // 1=ForReading
    HISCORE = parseInt(f1.ReadLine())
    f1.close()
}
and bla bla bla...
```

in folder files;

**cmdgfx_gdi.exe**

**cmdgfx_input.exe**

**cmdwiz.exe**

**dlc.exe**

***Question;*** can i use (C++ - C - python) that different programing languages like this example ".bat" file?

and how?

If you want to inspect That BAT game it's name is; "***cmdrunner***"

Answer (score 1):

This file is a hack. It consists of two parts:

- The batch code

  - If you look carefully you’ll see that most if this code is actually a JavaScript multiline comment starting at the end of line 1 and ending after `exit /b 0`.
- The JavaScript part

The batch script does some stuff that may or may not be called upon by the JavaScript part and then launches “itself” using `cscript`, the Console-based Windows Script Host.

The first line does not produce an error in either Batch or JavaScript.

You can use any combination of languages as long as it’s an interpreted language (otherwise you’ll have to compile and run the resulting program) and as long as you can craft a file that is valid for both in the critical parts.

It’s mostly pointless though.